# Run Command Prompt externally in R

Tags: r, shell, cmd, windows-console

I'm writing a script in R to switch between different crypto currency mining algorithms. I'm using R to determine the most profitable algorithm from a list of algorithms that is obtained with the following code:

```
library(rvest)

html_body <- read_html("https://whattomine.com/coins?utf8=%E2%9C%93&eth=true&factor%5Beth_hr%5D=70.0&factor%5Beth_p%5D=280.0&grof=true&factor%5Bgro_hr%5D=116.0&factor%5Bgro_p%5D=420.0&x11gf=true&factor%5Bx11g_hr%5D=39.0&factor%5Bx11g_p%5D=340.0&cn=true&factor%5Bcn_hr%5D=1660.0&factor%5Bcn_p%5D=280.0&eq=true&factor%5Beq_hr%5D=1270.0&factor%5Beq_p%5D=380.0&lre=true&factor%5Blrev2_hr%5D=128000.0&factor%5Blrev2_p%5D=380.0&ns=true&factor%5Bns_hr%5D=2800.0&factor%5Bns_p%5D=380.0&lbry=true&factor%5Blbry_hr%5D=920.0&factor%5Blbry_p%5D=380.0&bk2bf=true&factor%5Bbk2b_hr%5D=5500.0&factor%5Bbk2b_p%5D=380.0&bk14=true&factor%5Bbk14_hr%5D=8700.0&factor%5Bbk14_p%5D=420.0&pas=true&factor%5Bpas_hr%5D=3400.0&factor%5Bpas_p%5D=420.0&bkv=true&factor%5Bbkv_hr%5D=NaN&factor%5Bbkv_p%5D=NaN&factor%5Bcost%5D=0.16&sort=Profit&volume=0&revenue=current&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bittrex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bleutrade&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=btc_e&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=bter&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=c_cex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=cryptopia&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=poloniex&factor%5Bexchanges%5D%5B%5D=yobit&dataset=Main&commit=Calculate&adapt_q_280x=0&adapt_q_380=0&adapt_q_fury=0&adapt_q_470=0&adapt_q_480=0&adapt_q_750Ti=0&adapt_q_10606=0&adapt_q_1070=0&adapt_q_1080=0&adapt_q_1080Ti=2&adapt_1080Ti=true")
data <- html_body %>%
  html_nodes(".table-vcenter div+ div") %>%
  html_text()
data <- gsub("\n +", "", data)

coins <- vector("character")
algorithms <- vector("character")

coins <- data[seq(1,length(data),2)]
algorithms <- data[seq(2,length(data),2)]

profitability <- html_body %>%
  html_nodes(".table-vcenter td:nth-child(8) strong") %>%
  html_text()
profitability <- gsub("\n +", "", profitability)
```

I'm intending to check profitability every hour or so, but I'll add that in later. My question is: what is the best way to run an external command prompt for running each miner. For example, I tried using:

```
system("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Documents\\Miners\\ccminer-1.2-windows\\x86\\ccminer.exe")
```

which works, but R can no longer do anything else. In addition, I haven't found a way to stop the code from running without manually hitting escape. As you might have realised, I haven't done anything withe shell commands in R before, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ```system("C:\\Users\\Alex\\Documents\\Miners\\ccminer-1.2-windows\\x86\\ccminer.exe", wait=FALSE)``` should solve it.

Comment: @AGore. Thanks for your reply. Is there a way for R to open an external command promt or at least to see what the console is outputting?

Comment: Creating a process attached to a new console is a basic Windows feature, implemented as the `CreateProcess` creation flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`. R should support this. But, even if it doesn't, if its `system` function executes the command line via `cmd.exe /c`, then you can at least use CMD's `start` command.